# All rows are not exporting in sql file

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I am new to oracle 11g ,Please help me I am exporting table into sql file but all rows are not exporting.Table has around 25000 rows.I am following right click on table name export data->insert ,file format is filename.sql.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is from SQL Developer? It isn't really clear what problem you are having. How many insert statements do you get, how are you checking how many you expect, are you sure you're querying and exporting the same copy of the table (from the same schema), do you have a filter on your export... not enough to go on to help you really.

Comment: what IDE are you using?